# Reading data from a published Google Sheets with a script tag throws a `net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to read data with JS from a published Google Sheets and passing a callback to process the JSON feed (`https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/<SPREADSHEET_ID>/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData`). Then I make the request with a `<script>` with that src. I had no issues whatsoever using this method just a few weeks ago. But now I keep getting a 403 error (`net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`). Any ideas what has changed to prevent this from working as it normally did?

I can see the JSON feed when opening the link directly in my browser, I only get the error when making the request with `<script>`.

This is the error I get:

`GET https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/<MY_SPREADSHEET_ID>/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData&pli=1&authuser=0 net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Comment: I am not seeing an issue with this, are you sure you made the sheet public?

Comment: @Ramakay Yes. It all works when I open the link directly in my browser, I can see all the JSON. But it doesn't work at all when I call the request using an html script tag (which I've been doing the whole time and had worked).

Comment: Can you post a MVCE with how you are embedding this and trying to parse it.

Comment: Hey @Ramakay. I just figured out what the issue is– You are right! There is no issue with this at all. The thing is though, I had the file in a Shared Drive in my G-Suites account. But my organization has made it so that files in Shared Drives cannot be shared outside the org.  I just moved the file to my own Drive and it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is stored in a Shared Drive in your G Suite account and the organization does not allow for the files in the Shared Drives to be shared outside of the organization, the solution for this is to move the file in your Drive.